# incomplete vertical lines

Tags: tabularx

I have a problem with tabularx: the vertical lines don't go all the way to the bottom: I'm guessing it's due to adding a math equation in the 1st cell.
How can I do to have complete lines?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c||*{7}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}X|}}\hline
    volume d'eau (L)& 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.9 & 1.1 & 1.3 & 1.5 \\ 
    \hline
    force (N) & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15  \\ 
    \hline 
    Résistance ($\textrm{k}\Omega$) &  &  &  &  & & & &  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Remove the last `&` in your "Resistance" row.

Comment: Never ignore errors!!!  The result of your example is `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`  after any error then the PDF is not intended to be usable, just a possible debugging aid. If you are asking here for help after an error please show the error message not describe the pdf output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a spurious `&` in the last line. I also suggest a slightly different layout, where the double vertical line  interrupts the inner horizontal lines, which can be obtained with `hhline`, some vertical padding at the top of cells with `\extrarowheight`, and a simpler way to typeset `kΩ` with `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c||*{7}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    volume d'eau (L)& 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.9 & 1.1 & 1.3 & 1.5 \\
    \hline
    force (N) & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15 \\
    \hline
    Résistance (\si{\kohm}) & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\vskip 1cm

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c||*{7}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
    volume d'eau (L)& 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.9 & 1.1 & 1.3 & 1.5 \\
    \hhline{-||-------}
    force (N) & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15 \\
    \hhline{-||-------}
    Résistance (\si{\kohm}) & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I add the missing `\begin{document}` and try to compile your code, I end up with an error message such as

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

which tells us that there is an extra `&` somewhere in your table.

As soon as you get an error message, do not look at the resulting .pdf document.
Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

To get rid of the error message, delete the last `&` from the "Résistance" row and you will end up with a compilable example resulting in the following output. Such an extra `&`can be spotted more easily if you align all `&`s in your code, just as I did in the below MWE.

[image]

Additionally, I recommend using the `siunitx` package for the units, as shown in the following example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c||*{7}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}X|}}\hline
    volume d'eau (\si{\liter})  & 0.3 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.9 & 1.1 & 1.3 & 1.5 \\ 
    \hline
    force (\si{\newton})        & 3   & 5   & 7   & 9   & 11  & 13  & 15  \\ 
    \hline 
    Résistance (\si{\kilo\ohm}) &     &     &     &     &     &     &     \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks !
I already use sinuitx in my document but since I had this table problem, I left it aside